# io.Copy timeout when disable keepalive

Tags: go

When i disable linux keepalive with

```bash
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=0
```

and run follow code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9390")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("net listen fail, reason: [%s]\n", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        defer listen.Close()

        for {
            conn, err := listen.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("net accept fail, reason: [%s]\n", err.Error())
                continue
            }

            _, err = io.Copy(conn, conn)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("net Copy fail, reason: [%s]\n", err.Error())
                continue
            }
            conn.Close()
        }
    }()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9390")
            fmt.Println("tcp client resolve success: ", tcpAddr.String())
            tcpConn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("tcp connect fail: ", err.Error())
                return
            }

            time.Sleep(100 * time.Second)
            tcpConn.Close()
            fmt.Println("tcp end")
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

}
```

io.Copy will return "splice: connection timed out"

If I enable keepalive with

```bash
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3
```

io.Copy will be ok

I try the tcp client to send packet with 1 second interval and disable tcp_keepalive, it will be ok too.

and I write another code to instead io.Copy

```golang
            buf := make([]byte, 10)
            for {
                conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(30 * time.Second))
                n, err := conn.Read(buf)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("read fail: ", err.Error())
                    break
                }

                _, err = conn.Write(buf[:n])
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("write fail: ", err.Error())
                    break
                }
            }
            conn.Close()
```

It will read timeout after 15s, the 30s no work

why that will happen, it is too strange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answser:
When "kernel tcp stack" use keepalive detect the network, the net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 0 will be timeout when "kernel tcp stack" need to send keepalive